# Conditional Data Validation based on Empty Cell

Tags: validation, google-sheets, array-formulas

While in google spreadsheets, I am trying to have a data validation in B2 based on conditions in D2.

**I have tried**

```
=arrayformula(if(D2="",Sheet2!A1:A3))
```

**The Problem**

Just doesn't seem to work and overlaps existing data.

**Sheet 1**
[image]

**Sheet 2**

[image]

Is there a better way to do this? Can it be done using formulas?

Comment: Try to get this to work first without an array formula. When it works, try building the arrayformula around it. Not really sure what you're trying to do in your formula as your last if statement returns a range when E2 is empty...

Comment: Actually I made a mistake, it was supposed to be D2

Comment: Column D:N is queried from another sheet. Column B: data validation should be Cleared if column D becomes empty.